# what is a good c# data structure with direct access?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, data-access

I'm building a game in Unity and I need a good data structure that lets me access a key/property directly with optimal performance.

What I mean is for example in javascript I can do something like

```
var myData = {};

for (let data in somedata) {
  myData[data] = someValue;
}

console.log(myData['directToken']);
```

What can I use in C# that would let me do the same/similar?

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @MickyD no I'm programming in C# in unity, javascript is the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NameValueCollection`;

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection();
var someData = new List<string>(){ "directToken"};
foreach (var data in someData)
{
    collection[data] = "someValue";
}
Console.WriteLine(collection["directToken"]);
```

Also, you could use `Dictionary` with similar way instead of `NameValueCollection`. Only difference is `NameValueCollection` can contain duplicate keys.

Comment: much appreciated, is there any source for benchmarking performance like there is jsperf.com but for c#?

Comment: Actually, I don't know this kind of site. But Visual Studio performance and diagnostic tools is your best friend.

Comment: http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-collection-for-string-lookups has some good collection comparison data, just a few years old.

Comment: Just out of interest, why is it beneficial to use a `NameValueCollection` over a `Dictionary`? Like you mentioned `NameValueCollection` can contain duplicate keys but is not that rather unuseful when creating a save data structure?

Comment: One more here ruling for Dictionary. Only if you need duplicates, else use Dictionary.

Comment: yes lucky for me I do not need any duplicates but really I can't conceive when having duplicate would be beneficial especially if you are looking for a specific value from a specific key, perhaps you can return multiple values and figure it out from there but seems counter intuitive